# Bias of an estimated Gaussian density

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, bias, unbiased-estimator

I have an iid sample, $X_1,\dots,X_N \in R^d$, from a multivariate normal density with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

I am estimating the density $p(y) = N(y| \mu, \Sigma)$, using $\hat{p}(y) = N(y| \hat{\mu}, \hat{\Sigma})$, where $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ are sample mean and covariance matrix and $y$ is a fixed vector.

I would like to work out the bias of $\hat{p}(y)$, that is $E\{\hat{p}(y) - p(y)\}$. Using the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34165/expected-value-of-the-log-determinant-of-a-wishart-matrix) and [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0608064), it should be possible to derive the bias of $\log \hat{p}(y)$, but this is not quite what I need.

Given the Gaussian setting, I expected such a result to be "out there", but I was unable to find it. Maybe someone is aware of relevant results?